# How to read multiple tables from a Database using Datastage for Count?

Tags: database, oracle, db2, datastage

As I can read only one table I have to read and make the job reusable can one someone help me?

'''SELECT '#psDBProject.Table_Name#' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) AS COUNT, FROM #DBProject.Scehma#.#DBProject.Table_Name#;'''

Comment: you formatted the code in the wrong way. It should be using this ( ` ) mark, not the ( ' ) mark

Comment: maybe there's a typo in 'Scehma'. And you're not using the same variables for the tablename ( the first one is prefixed with 'ps')

Answer (score 1):

Extend your SQL capabilities.  Depending upon exactly what you want, perhaps UNION ALL would be a good joiner.

```
SELECT #psDBProject.Table_Name1# AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) AS ROWCOUNT FROM #DBProject.Schema#.#DBProject.Table_Name# UNION ALL SELECT '#psDBProject.Table_Name2#', COUNT(1) FROM #DBProject.Schema#.#DBProject.Table_Name#;
```